# Quotation marks cancelling out command in bash to pass to variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, pipe

I'm trying to run a command that grabs my current IP address (or addresses) and saves this to a variable so that I can then see on screen. I want to do this so that I can run this in a script and use the variable in a loop.

```
userip='ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d: -f2  |  awk '{print $1}''

echo $userip
```

Everytime I run this command, its basically getting the speech marks mixed up and thus not running whole command.

It's really just got `'ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d: -f2  |  awk '` in the single quotations.

Any advice would be extremely helpful thanks.

Comment: You cannot embed single-quotes within a single-quoted string (`'{print $1}'`).  In fact, the syntax highlighting of your own question could serve as a clue.

Comment: **thus not running whole command** Doing `echo` won't run the `ifconfig` command. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I've tried mixing up the double and single quotations. 
My echo command is just to output the result, hoping my IP address will appear.

Comment: @robot420 Did you mean to assign *the result* of the command to `userip`? In that case `$()` is what you want, not single quotes.

Comment: Yes $() worked. Thanks a lot. @Biffen 
Yeah when i ran the command without assigning it to the variable, it did give me 2 addresses. This should be simple to fix :)

Comment: @robot420 This is an excellent example of how you could have gotten the right answer much quicker (or even found it yourself) if you had *properly described the problem from the start*!

Comment: @Biffen honestly i sat here for about 10 minutes changing the title to what I thought was good. What would you have said?

Comment: @robot420 Well, a clear description of the problem, including expected output and actual output are common ingredients of a good question. Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: :Voted to reopen as the duplicate doesn't answer the needs of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that the single quotes you have are incorrect, they should be grave accent  so, not ' but instead  `

Comment: Or better yet: `$()`

Answer (score 0):

Check that your command string to isolate the IP address is contained in back quotes. The back quote ` is different than the single quote ' or double quote " (assuming the command line works for your OS). Thus:

```
userip=`ifconfig | grep "inet addr:" | cut -d: -f2  |  awk '{print $1}'`
```

The back quotes cause the command to be executed and the results returned. The backquote is below the tilda ~ on most keyboards. (not sure the back quote is appearing in my answer. Just getting used to Stack Exchange.)

Comment: Awesome thanks, I actually never used the back quotes. Cheer buddy.